# I have a ml500 2003 i bout a key from some were eles am trying to reprogram my key am in Woodbridge v.a

Tags: electrical

Ml500 2003 benz truck am trying to get on the road today yare cant reprogram my key? Ihave the real key but it broke

Comment: @dlu - No doubt about it ... they registered for this one, so would be more inclined to close the other one.

Comment: Looks like the name is linked to both, the other one has been edited and has some good comments on it. So maybe this one?

Answer (score 1):

You can only get it programmed at the Mercedes dealership.